# WPF MVVM Dependency Injection for UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I'm developing a WPF .Net Core 5 Application using MVVM Pattern, and I'm trying to use Dependency Injection to learn something new.

I've just modified the App.xaml.cs class as follows and after initial login, I can reach MainWindow showing as expected:

```
       public partial class App : Application
        {
            private readonly ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    
            public App()
            {
                ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
                ConfigureServices(services);
                _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            }
    
            private void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddTransient<frmSQLConnection>();
                services.AddTransient<frmLogin>();
                services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
            }
    
            protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
            {
                if ((SuccessfullyConnected || _serviceProvider.GetService<frmSQLConnection>().ShowDialog() == true) && _serviceProvider.GetService<frmLogin>().ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                    _serviceProvider.GetService<MainWindow>().Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Shutdown();
                }
            }
}
```

My doubts come now because MainWindow.xaml will be composed by a RibbonMenu on the top and a TabControl right below, like this example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWUMi.png)

My question is what would be a good implementation of Dependency Injection for UserControls?
I've read some articles speaking about Composite Application but it seemed to be more useful for nested UserControls than in my case.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance for availability

Answer (score 0):

If you are conforming to the MVVM pattern, then you would set up ViewModels for each user control and use DI in the constructor or method bodies to inject the 'services' you need. Then you can use something like PRISM (MVVM Framework) to trigger events that other ViewModels can subscribe to. It also provides mechanisms for navigation within an MVVM application as well.

EDIT:
You may also want to look into using a 'shell' view and then user controls inside. This will enable you to swap/navigate to different user controls within the 'shell' view. Which can have its own view model and global events, etc.

PRISM Resources: https://prismlibrary.com/docs/index.html